# Fetch user who have flagged a taxonomy term

Tags: rules, flags

My users can flag a taxonomy term.
I need to notify the user who have flagged a taxonomy term when a new content with the flagged taxonomy term is created. I need to do this with rules module.

Comment: What do you mean with "notify the user"? Would you like to send an e-mail to the user?